Could saltpeter be discovered from fertilizer?
One day, while going down a black-powder rabbit hole, I stumbled upon the neat historical fact that, in various times and places in the early modern period, urine was used as the source of saltpeter to make gunpowder. This got my worldbuilding gears turning, so I came up with the following:

In order to farm previously barren areas, farmers started mixing pee and poop and using that to fertilize their fields.

A good while later, some tinkering farmer mixed wood and ash in with his fertilizer, and, in the process, he discovered saltpeter.

This discovery of a new substance causes a stir within the fledgeling science of chemistry (which, in my world, at this point, is sort of like alchemy without the weird esoteric stuff), and more intellectual individuals start to examine it.

One scientist mixes the "extract of crap" with charcoal and sulphur and ends up making a highly explosive powder that could prove to be useful...


(All of this take place in a technological level comparable to Europe 1000 to 1600 AD with no magic)
However, I can't quite figure out if the second step in this timeline would be feasible. Could saltpeter be discovered, without looking for it, within fertilizer? At first I would think that more unexpected discoveries have happened in our world, but I would like to err on the side of caution and ask the people of the internet to answer.

Yes, niter forms naturally in poorly maintained stables, where the feces mixed with straw and urine accumulate. On the other hand, niter (the crystalline form or potassium nitratre) occurs naturally. It has been known since the antiquity. The discovery was that the process could be accelerated artificially in purposely-made nitraries; the substance itself did not need to be discovered.

@AlexP I never realized niter was naturally occuring. Where does it tend to be found?

Dried and crystalized run-offs from the guano in bat caves: "Bracken Cave in Texas, USA. The cave is the summer home to an estimated 20 million Mexican free-tailed bats". This has been going on for hundreds of thousands of years in the same caves. It's what was done since the 18th century by Europeans, mining of bat-guano. @RyanFunk

Could - Sure, anyone Could discover it.
The issue that you have is identifying it as something unique And useful
This is where I think you will struggle. Farmers are a very Pragmatic bunch. Innovation that has a direct link to their interests are generally well-received, whereas innovations that have a less direct link to their interests are much lower on their list of priorities.
And when it comes to Farming (I live in NZ, know many Farmers) the list of Priorities is:

Long
Neverending
and even after working 120 hour weeks (like during Harvest season) it is still not done

Farmers as a rule do not have the time or energy to pursue esoteric ideas (not all Farmers) because they are generally so busy with looking after the Land, the Animals, the Fences, the Crops etc...
You need someone who has time and energy to pursue their curiosity purely for the sake of curiosity - and as a general rule - that isnt Farmers.
Note: This may see as a bit of an attack on Farmers, it is not, I want to reiterate - Farmers work bloody hard. The stories you hear about Farmers toughing it out through horrendous wounds and putting in 18 hour work days are not myths or hyperbole - They are up at the crows fart in dawn, are on-call 24-7 for any issues on their Farm, they are often their neighbors only source of help (The nearest Ambulance is probably 2 hours away...). I did some time helping on a Farm and it was hard work. I am grateful for that hard work and the food they provide - my point is - when you are working as hard as Farmers do, it is nigh-impossible to sit down and have the hours upon hours needed to tinker with something, controlling for imperfections to extract out a purified chemical and then spend even more time finding uses for it.

The average medieval farmer only worked ~4 hours a day most days.  Yes, planting and harvest season could be very busy, but that would not be every work week for them. They very often had one or more secondary crafts that they practiced to fill the rest of thier time during growing seasons.

@Nosajimiki - I have heard that stat before, but suffice to say I am skeptical of how it was obtained.

@Nosajimiki This video explains it well. Even if the average medieval peasant only had to work the fields for about 4 hours per day (which I'm pretty skeptical about), they still had many other things to do afterwards. This was preindustrial society, so you had to be more or less self-sufficient. You wanted water? Go to the well and fetch it. You wanted food? Go to wherever you store it, and cook some (after you get firewood and start the fire too). And if you have leftovers, you couldn't save it, so that's not on the menu.

Instead of the farmer being the one to find it, it is far more likely that a teenager skipping chores would. Old stories had many a "lad whose job it was to clear out the ashes" being the creative person using existing technology in new ways.

@TheDemonLord It is based on observations of African, South American, and South Asian societies that still follow medieval(ish) agricultural practices.  So, it's not what is inferred from historical text, but actual first person accounts of people who still live this way.  Yes, there are a couple months out of the year that they work a lot of 12+ hour days, but those are the exceptions, not the rule.

@RHF  Yes, there was more of certain kinds of domestic work to be done, but there was also a lot less other kinds of domestic work.  Driving kids to school, tournaments, and other events, helping them with homework, meeting with teachers, and signing up for testing, summer camps, etc. Grocery shopping 1-3 times a week at sprawling stores that may be several miles away instead of storing a whole year's worth of staple foods in your home or walking a few feet out to your garden to pick whatever is ready.

Then there is the paperwork: dozens of bills to track, permission slips, complex tax codes, contracts for every damn thing.  HOA requirements to mow your lawn, trim your hedges, and pull weeds.  Automobile and appliance maintenance.  etc. etc. etc.  When you consider all the stuff you don't have to do in a primitive society, spending a few minutes a day gathering water and firewood and grinding your own grains is not actually that big of a deal.

As others have already pointed out, yes. The problem is, making sufficient amount of saltpeter this way takes enormous effort. Once you "mine" all the saltpeter from the sand underneath the existing old stables, from under bat guano in caves, and from the bird guano around the cliffs where seagulls nest, your supply of new saltpeter is going to drop to 1% of what you need. Nitraries to capture saltpeter take months to establish, and longer to produce any substantial amounts.
So even when it was discovered, it would take decades if not longer to go from "enough gunpowder for one minor battle" to "enough gunpowder to wage a whole war with", even if your entire kingdom/empire was shoveling manure and running with buckets of piss all day.
One interesting option I can think of, is if your Kingdom has access to some kind of seaweed-rich sea. Beached rotting seaweed is a great, self-renewing source of fertilizer and saltpeter, and unlike manure/guano/human waste it does not run out as easily. Moreover, if the rotting seaweed is spread over a sandy beach, it forms a natural nitrate bed in its own. They would just need to rake it a bit further inland so that tides would not wash away the precious saltpeter into the sea.

Your entire proposal lines up with actual history

Gunpowder was discovered in Europe between 1000 to 1600 AD
Saltpeter was already documented as forming in pee and poop long before the discovery gunpowder.  It was already widely mined and mass produced during the time of the Roman Empire.

Why Gunpowder is a perfectly reasonable accidental discovery
There are a lot of legends about how gunpowder was discovered, most of it revolving around outlandish experiments, but in all likelihood, it was an accidental discovery. With the most logical explanation being soap making.  Going all the way back to antiquity, there have been 3 main chemicals used in various types of soap.  Saltpeter based soaps were the most common kind of soap used in the Ancient world.  Lye based soaps mostly phased them out in the medieval period because Lye is easy to make from the waste wood ash that was already being produced in every household. Lastly there is sulfur based soaps which were more of a niche product dating all the way back to the Ancient Egyptians and was primarily for treating skin diseases.
So, anyone looking to make an all-purpose soap might logically want to mix all 3 ingredients.  I'd say it is not only possible, but probable that people were washing thier skin with gunpowder based soaps for centuries before its explosive properties were put to other uses, and even if they were not mixed into the same soap, it would have been very likely for any soap maker to keep large amounts of all three ingredients under the same roof; so, your average medieval soap maker was always just one little accident away from one of history's most significant discoveries.
